# Dimmer causing light flickers

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I have two of the fixtures in the photograph mounted above a double vanity.  I installed a dimmer switch since the six bulbs are way too bright no matter what time of day.  Dimmer switch dims fine but the lights flash brightly when you first turn them on, then they steadily flicker/pulsate when dimmed.  I thought it might be something with the total wattage of the six bulbs...  I took out one bulb from each fixture and it improved slightly at first but one day later, back to flash and flicker.  How can I get the dimmer to work correctly with these fixtures and bulbs?

[image]

Comment: What are you using for a dimmer, and for lightbulbs for that matter?

Comment: when you say "flash brightly", how long is said flash?

Comment: Flash is immediately after turning the lights on, for a millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

Are those decorative LED bulbs? Some LEDs do not play nice with analog (old-school rheostat) dimmers.

You'll want a LED dimmer switch, or verify that the LED bulbs you have are dimmable (some are, some are not).

Comment: It also helps to sometimes mix different brands of bulbs in a multi-lamp fixture that's on a dimmer; the different manufacturers will typically have different power supply designs in their LED lamps which won't have as much of a tendency to resonate with each other in the circuit at less-than-full power.  Or better yet, put a single incandescent in there between the two LEDs and that should serve to dampen out the load imbalances in the circuit.